# Hibernate eager loading not fetching all child rows

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate version 4.3.10

I have parent/child relationship as described in the example. There are occasions when we expect only one row to be returned when querying for Provider. In this case, we limit the criteria by calling setMaxResults method to 1.

Dump of SQL revealed that hibernate makes outer join calls which ends up returning more than one row, but because of limit set on criteria, only first child row is read from database.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "F_PROVIDER")
    public class Provider {
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "provider", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private final Set<CredentialFieldDefinition> credentialFieldDefinitionList;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "F_CRED_FIELDS", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "name", "provider_id" }) })
public class CredentialFieldDefinition {
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Provider.class, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROVIDER_ID", nullable = false, unique = false)
    private Provider provider;
}
```

How do I convince to return me full child set when I am reading only row?

Comment: You talke nicely to it. If you want someone to solve your problem you need to detail a lot more , like provide relevant code where you call setMaxResults, show the dump and all that. Stories are nice and all, but you don't convince hibernate, you program it.

Comment: Why can you not leave out the set max results if you know only 1 object will be returned? You could load the relationship lazy. Otherwise use a sub query to find the id of the object you want to load and limit the results on the sub query. Your main query then has no set max results.

Comment: Can you show the mapping in the child object `CredentialFieldDefinition` ?

Comment: @Arkantos, added requested informatio

Comment: @Gerhard, there are reasons why it has to be eagerly loaded. Also all queries need to have limit as per organization policy and is enforced by core data access layer. The key issue here is not the design of existing code, but what can we do to change outer join.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [SUBSELECT](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/FetchMode.html#SUBSELECT) fetch mode:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "provider", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private final Set<CredentialFieldDefinition> credentialFieldDefinitionList;
```

This way `credentialFieldDefinitionList` will be initialized in a separate query.